# Disjoint force directed layout graph in Vega

Tags: vega

I am trying to use Vega library for creating a force transform graph for my application. The graph is disconnected.
My understanding of both Vega and Force directed transforms are a bit limited but I've tried to hunt many examples from Vega and also checked out a bit of D3 to make it work but couldn't.

The problem: When I try to use the default [force directed example in Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/force-directed-layout/), I see that disconnected components of graph can go out of canvas when user is interacting with one of the components.
Here's a simple list of nodes and links for a graph with two connected components that can be used as a test.

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "node-data",
      "values": [
        {"name": "A", "group": 1, "index": 0},
        {"name": "B", "group": 2, "index": 1},
        {"name": "C", "group": 1, "index": 2},
        {"name": "D", "group": 1, "index": 3},
        {"name": "E", "group": 2, "index": 4},
        {"name": "F", "group": 1, "index": 5}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "link-data",
      "values": [
        {"source": 0, "target": 3, "value": 1},
        {"source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 1},
        {"source": 2, "target": 3, "value": 1},
        {"source": 4, "target": 5, "value": 1}
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I tried to follow this [example in D3](https://observablehq.com/@d3/disjoint-force-directed-graph) which seemed to be exactly my use case.
The D3 example mentioned use of positioning forces (rather than central force) along with link and nbody/many-body force

From D3 example:

```
  const forceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
  const forceLink = d3.forceLink(links).id(({index: i}) => N[i]);
  if (nodeStrength !== undefined) forceNode.strength(nodeStrength);
  if (linkStrength !== undefined) forceLink.strength(linkStrength);

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", forceLink)
      .force("charge", forceNode)
      .force("x", d3.forceX())
      .force("y", d3.forceY())
      .on("tick", ticked);
```

Here is my example vega spec https://gist.github.com/guptanagendra/617457f8a44cacac36ee1ead59b6ba72

I tried similar force combinations in Vega (uncomment some forces in spec above), but all nodes are put in one corner when positioning force are used. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your example that works. The default parameters are based on trial and error.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-0W4UCsXCpCi20S+IuvGvBG2JDEOjhAAaA012tQ40oQpAYYjUZjcZ5lqTdtTWblubsBcw4QAmqWg1sq6HDZHjdHTSBzbyrVsU2mZdmCegnQDEgOte83HcIHAR+GjSbYx94FAzEw2N9F6B5EoVGoJKcAMp+oLaanKJA9aoebJIJKkDU8juDQnzaKumAUv0Mg5qcbigRu5bbvce4gI+qDPCAcCkOImAPCu4QIBeRioAgUS7lEmCPAAhNhcC4ZQTDRJgEgQAAurEzjhmwjikeRcC-Ci-yAugyG7rioB0bh+EgBAhHEXxFJwLUWRCWicGgdoAA+WmVIo2qulJeGnI8clEWwJFkUpsg8eInHMjxim7r8bHaAAfE4Dm8VZu5kaQ1FqSJICfOEAAUACUAy-t4aCYPpcBQmxrq3lAyiqOopwAOJ2DgrhEtUZFOto-jeLhRjhOUuFZP+QQhM49DQW6CL5Yh7ziAwRhGDI6GYUZMlmQpPnKaQiiBQi8FgQAvNNem0toAD85RBAgEXaKgQEnIlyUKKl94ZegABiYQpCxxUKH6ihYgdnhlAcCAdWuEjaL8T3CUgqSqjyECNbBZrneksZUoOqBiahPWSThxljtctxGBpV4yL8wnjZpABkqMgZ8lC9BsIxbRxcgAigGEdgqhhva1+GYb9ICaAMthRFKqDVsycCiuMro0wAQvTiiM2g4IyKzC5Lu6IBKrz-PM0L4ZswLnPLiAXqS4J0vjvIoq6grYsAKIq0zgvq3LqAACzawiB364KMsawsW2iwinpmL4ROU08oBiEUMUVjIF3qseupA5u0p4p7Xj0r7apwAHQflnSrph97ht+9HaCByAZb0gnUTh2gJuR4o-sLLHWdJQT0B3Ao7tNacUAWZ4Aw9jgCKeOsdwDDZyBJjervoPlLt+lFNBwEYEYgAzgkwlO8bvB7sCIAiUBomQnjhOC4xQNCiUpooZhU6TfeKpSIBNwiA0WQMhzC9bIBuHzCBGhTh-k67U-gyfyhkOqo2iQhwr6DQNwyJn6Bk3DJCa2hpqTVmtURawA3CfHWvlSgnxYhAKQYqSg4QoRrW0PAxBmNHjjA4u4cI60JqPDpElCSH9Zjf1ONRCaloAFALJqA2kMl8FII6l1Uh3DOpQmhATeidd5BGnokEH+oB4KdSNBXXotd66jRkPBEeY8J5Sink6PmZhZ4Z2BoMGAdBNoyE+B4Qo+EPazFhrXBGIBwjmIpHI6x7cPjIkXCAJG6loZHD0TDVxIBwTaAAFQbVJFYCkISwlkicVPQoigxBSP0cHdAOA2CmEkVvKecV-QQF-A-EmJ9wjNzgjdXkxi7APnEPhfU2x-Crkus4m4AT6kXVjFo1864fHNLhiuTpm8tEuN6bfMpUUyn7xGbnD4EjVKmKaTYj4djgFWJ6bXdxrpooIm+HM9AZj8hOIlCUMgIxukLPHl2QsJZryTO9vYgYwD7GOOPto+ixyYDzICXmbsfYt54k2YozqNAxEyDsBEyxskhmnCdj6VcAZfnSNGX3C8shkSHNeSclZZz8oqijvCm5jtTBmAGE7GSTsB4oBkFYWF3tMUBOhb6f0MUZRl1dKfU4KwRgqPvo-XuIAyUUynhk6qAEtw7lQiIxURovEiQ9nFNguijSZ1OAAYgKAMw58q4AAHUgUYuSeWSsAgZTZO5HkzwBTMJso9ISjl7yQVwAAI4MBoP4D5wz-laNVCU61FwBiJzgCWdAwkGAIEoP6lBfqc7eH7EGgEIaw1RrgFgxuUdMCBsJpBUNKdMARoLv7GNGb43ZuTfjKEQA)

Vega documentation and examples:

- [Force Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/force/#forces)
- [Force Directed Layout Example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/force-directed-layout/)
- [Beeswarm Plot Example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/beeswarm-plot/)

[image]

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
      "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
      "width": 700,
      "height": 500,
      "padding": 0,
      "autosize": "none",
      "signals": [
        {"name": "cx", "update": "width / 2"},
        {"name": "cy", "update": "height / 2"},
        {
          "name": "nodeRadius",
          "value": 10,
          "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 50, "step": 1}
        },
        {
          "name": "nodeCharge",
          "value": -30,
          "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -100, "max": 10, "step": 1}
        },
        {
          "name": "linkDistance",
          "value": 15,
          "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1}
        },
    
    
        { "name": "gravityX", "value": 0.1, "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 1} },
        { "name": "gravityY", "value": 0.1, "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 1} },
    
    
    
        {"name": "static", "value": false, "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}},
        {
          "description": "State variable for active node fix status.",
          "name": "fix",
          "value": false,
          "on": [
            {
              "events": "symbol:mouseout[!event.buttons], window:mouseup",
              "update": "false"
            },
            {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "fix || true"},
            {
              "events": "[symbol:mousedown, window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
              "update": "xy()",
              "force": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "description": "Graph node most recently interacted with.",
          "name": "node",
          "value": null,
          "on": [
            {"events": "symbol:mouseover", "update": "fix === true ? item() : node"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "description": "Flag to restart Force simulation upon data changes.",
          "name": "restart",
          "value": false,
          "on": [{"events": {"signal": "fix"}, "update": "fix && fix.length"}]
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "node-data",
          "values": [
            {"name": "A", "group": 1, "index": 0},
            {"name": "B", "group": 2, "index": 1},
            {"name": "C", "group": 1, "index": 2},
            {"name": "D", "group": 1, "index": 3},
            {"name": "E", "group": 2, "index": 4},
            {"name": "F", "group": 1, "index": 5}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "link-data",
          "values": [
            {"source": 0, "target": 3, "value": 1},
            {"source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 1},
            {"source": 2, "target": 3, "value": 1},
            {"source": 4, "target": 5, "value": 1}
          ]
        }
      ],
      "scales": [
        {
          "name": "color",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "domain": {"data": "node-data", "field": "group"},
          "range": {"scheme": "category20c"}
        }
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "name": "nodes",
          "type": "symbol",
          "zindex": 1,
          "from": {"data": "node-data"},
          "on": [
            {
              "trigger": "fix",
              "modify": "node",
              "values": "fix === true ? {fx: node.x, fy: node.y} : {fx: fix[0], fy: fix[1]}"
            },
            {"trigger": "!fix", "modify": "node", "values": "{fx: null, fy: null}"}
          ],
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "group"},
              "stroke": {"value": "white"},
    
             "xfocus": {"signal": "cx"},
              "yfocus": {"signal": "cy"}
    
    
            },
            "update": {
              "size": {"signal": "2 * nodeRadius * nodeRadius"},
              "cursor": {"value": "pointer"}
              
             
            }
          },
          "transform": [
            {
              "type": "force",
              "iterations": 300,
              "restart": {"signal": "restart"},
              "static": {"signal": "static"},
              "signal": "force",
              "forces": [
            
                {"force": "center", "x": {"signal": "cx"}, "y": {"signal": "cy"}},
    
                {"force": "x", "x": "xfocus", "strength": {"signal": "gravityX"}},
    
                {"force": "y", "y": "yfocus", "strength": {"signal": "gravityY"}},
    
                {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "linkDistance"}},
     
    
                {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge"}},
    
                {"force": "link", "links": "link-data", "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}}
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "path",
          "from": {"data": "link-data"},
          "interactive": false,
          "encode": {
            "update": {"stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}, "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}}
          },
          "transform": [
            {
              "type": "linkpath",
              "require": {"signal": "force"},
              "shape": "line",
              "sourceX": "datum.source.x",
              "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
              "targetX": "datum.target.x",
              "targetY": "datum.target.y"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```